# UIImageView stretch/repeat image on borders and maintain its quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a squared `UIImage`

[image]

I'm trying to create a `UIImageView` using this `UIImage` for any given rect which I'll be using as a border to another view on top of it.

I don't want to set the border of the `layer` manually but I would like to use this image.

**Example of desired output:**

[image]

I tried using `UIView`'s `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 300, 150)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

But the image is stretching and not returning the desired output

**Example output:**

[image]

Comment: why using image to create border. Programmatically create border and give it colour etc. What ever you want.

Comment: I was not able to achieve the exact same border and shadow of the image by changing the view's layer.

Comment: Use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` or `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` on your `UIImage`. Look at "Defining a Stretchable Image" part there: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage?language=objc#symbols

Comment: @Larme This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @iDev try the method shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically you can create border with shadow effect:

```
[view.layer setCornerRadius:5];
[view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];
[view.layer setShadowRadius:1.0];
[view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
```

Although if you want to do it using Xcode interface, you can do it as

1. Drag & drop your square image into Assets
2. Select image & click on "Show the Attribute Inspector"
3. In Slicing section select "Horizontal and Vertical" for Slices

Now Use it as you want you will have stretch image without any distortion

[image]

You can view image slice view on clicking "Show Slicing" at the bottom

[image]

You can also do it programatically using

[`resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624127-resizableimagewithcapinsets)

Comment: Thank you, I think its worth mentioning that it can be done programmatically using `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.